# Show the sum in c++ and after that add more sum cpp

Tags: c++, sum

Consider a program that asks the user for an integer value greater than 10, say 15. The program should then calculate the sum of all positive values up to 15 and now I need to "show the
current sum after adding each number".

For the first part I made everything like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int num = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    cout << " Please enter how many number you'd like to sum up\n";
    cin >> num;

    while (num <= 10)
    {
        cout << "Please enter an integer which is more than 10";
        cin >> num;
    }

    for ( int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        sum += i;
    }

    cout << "The total sum is : " <<  sum;
```

But now I dont know what should i do?

[It should look like this in the end.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sflmv.png)

Comment: What do you think how to achieve this? You are using `std::cout` all the time, so where is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include the desired output. Not a link to something, not a screenshot of the text, but the actual text.

Comment: "...now I need to..."   IMHO, perhaps your requirement is more "...now the code needs to...".  By removing yourself from the requirements, the difference between what you can do and what your software should do might help you reason about your software's goals and how to achieve them.  Then, maybe try to describe to your rubber ducky what the software shall do as its next step.  Initially, talk (out loud) to your ducky in human language (and skip quack-quack).  Use your favorite browser to search for  'rubber ducky software debugging'

Comment: also use different variable you are trying to get two values of some person and you place this in one variable make something like maxvalue and num

Comment: Remember functions?  Every requirement, such as a) "asks the user for an integer value greater than 10", and b) "[sw] should then calculate the sum of all positive values up to 15"  maybe should be a function.  IMHO, this will help and  even make your code more readable so others will find it easier to help..  Every function you write is (in essence) an application-focused-extension to the C++ language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by outputting the values used in the calculation, along with the 'running' total, inside your summation loop:

```c
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
{
    cout << sum << "  + " << i << " = " << sum + i << "\n";
    sum += i;
}
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.